# Decent salary in Bahrain

Tags: indian-citizens, salary, bahrain

A recruiter called me who is ready to offer 1100 Dinar per month (approx 2900 US$) as salary for a software developer role in Bahrain.

I am a single guy currently working in India with 4.3 years of experience leading an average lifestyle. Is this a good salary to live in a decent clean safe home, eat a typical average Indian food, come home yearly once and save at least 50K INR (approx 780 US$) per month?

If this is low, please let me know what would be the right salary?

Comment: **Do not make everyone guess about the Exchange rate of INR to Bahraini Dinars**. I have edited the question and added US$ as common currency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exchange rate tells me that 1100 bahraini dinars a month over a year is 35k dollars a year. The bahraini dinar is the second highest value currency in the world, which makes the number look small. 
According to my research and using conservative numbers you should be able to save 50k indian rupees a month. This is based on the average cost of living, and it may vary. Of course there is no harm in trying to negotiate a better salary.
You'd have to save 300 bahraini dollars a month to give 50k indian rupees.
The rent for an apartment in the city centre it seems is between 250 and 450 bahraini dinars a month and on average 345 bahraini dinars.
From looking at the expat arrivals forum, 950 bahraini dinars is decent for an indian with 3 or less years work experience. the source also says that food is at max 200 bd.
Anyways. At 13200 bd a year, you will be paid higher than the average salary of a software developer in bahrain which is only 10100bhd a year. 
http://www.payscale.com/research/BH/Job=Software_Developer/Salary
Overall I think you can save 50k indian rupees.
Thank you.